# Symfony Explorer-Like Nested Routing

Tags: symfony, symfony4

Let's say i have six pages like that:

```
data/home-page
data/apple-page
data/category1/apple-page
data/category1/kiwi-page
data/category1/category2/apple-page
data/category1/category2/pear-page
```

I want to route each of them to my PageController, but also respect the category the page is in, because the titles can double.

```
class PageController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * @Route("/wiki/{page}")
     */
    public function showPage($page = 'home')
    {
        # Some kind of validation
        # ...
        # And then something like that should happen:
        return $this->render('data/'.$page.'-page')
    }
}
```

If I call `localhost/wiki/apple` i obviously get the correct page, but how do i have to configure my Route to get `category1/apple` of `localhost/wiki/category1/apple`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Allow your page to be anything you fancy

```
class PageController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * @Route("/wiki/{page}", requirements={"page"=".*"})
     */
    public function showPage($page = 'home')
    {
        # Some kind of validation
        # ...
        # And then something like that should happen:
        return $this->render('data/'.$page.'-page')
    }
}
```